# Gitlab group permission management, access for developer

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ee

I have set up a Gitlab solution in our company.
We would like to be able to store our projects in groups. I would like each user to be able to create a project in the groups and to have the rights on his project.

From what I have seen:

- A user must have "developer" rights on the group to create a project.

  - With the "developer" right, the user is not a "maintainer" of his project (so he can't modify the parameters, nor push on the "master" branch !)
- A user with "maintainer" rights on the group can create a project and access the parameters of his project. However, he also becomes "maintainer" of other users' projects! This is not desired.

From what I could see, it is linked to this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17095 which is more than 4 years old!

What solution could you propose to me so that a user can create projects in a group, and that he has the rights on his project without having maintainer rights on the projects of other users.

Thank you.

(latest Gitlab-ee version, 14.7.0)